# Selecting input inside a form with few divs in the way

Tags: jquery, html

I have structure like this

```
<form id="from">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input>
        </div>
    <div/>
</form>
```

How to select that input if forms id is know?

i am trying something like this:

```
$("#from > input")
```

but its now working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `>` is the child selector and only selects the immediate descendant element, which the input is not. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: Try `#form` instead of `#from`  :p

Comment: sorry that not the proble, just misspelled :)

Comment: I elected to change the Id to form...to distiguish it as different to the element tag `form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("#from input")
```

`>` is immediate descendant selector

**OR**, You can use [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("#from").find('input')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use,

```
$("#form  input")
```

because input is not the direct child of form

Also you can try

```
$("#form>div>div>input")
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/rYAT3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#form input")`, as the `>` selects direct descendants only.